# Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working on MVC and Entity Framework. I have written a function for multiple record delete.

The model is:

```
public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            //this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller is:

```
public ActionResult DeleteMultipleCategories(int[] id)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Category item in _db.Categories.Where(x => id.Equals(x.CategoryID)).ToList())
                    _db.Categories.Remove(item);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
```

It is giving an error like

*"Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.".*

The statement "**id.Equals(x.CategoryID)).ToList()**" is responsible the error.

If I change it to **id.Contains(x.CategoryID)).ToList()**, it is working fine.
I don't want to use "**Contains**" as it will not give actual result e.g. if I want to delete the record no. 1 it will also delete record no. 11, 111 etc.

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Partha

Comment: How do you expect an array to equal an int?

Comment: public int CategoryID { get; set; }. Please view the model.

Comment: why are you using an array, if you want to delete multiple items that will do it using contains, if your only trying to delete one item you should use a single id or id[0]

Comment: Either you want to delete all Categories whose ID is contained in the `id` array or you don't. If you do, you need to use `Contains`. If the result isn't what you expected, you are probably passing the wrong IDs or have some other problem

Answer (score 1):

For the int datatype you have to use == as the comparator. So your linq statement should be something like `.where(m =>m.id == x.CategoryID).ToList()`

Comment: `id` is an array-typed *parameter*, not a property of the entity. Perhaps you didn't realize what the OP is trying to do? In any case, there's no difference between `==` and `Equals` as far as LINQ to Entities is concerned - both map to an equality check in SQL

Comment: .where(m =>m.id == x.CategoryID).ToList() is getting error "'WebApp1.Models.Category' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApp1.Models.Category' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"